# How to toggle multiple instances of a class using document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code below which is being used on a mobile navigation section of a website.

```
const toggleButton = document.querySelector(".header__nav-mobile .toggle");
const subMenu = document.querySelector(".header__nav-mobile .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu");

function toggleMenuItems() {
  if (toggleButton .classList.contains("open")) {
    toggleButton.classList.remove("open");
    subMenu.classList.remove("open");
  } else {
    toggleButton.classList.add("open");
    subMenu.classList.add("open");
  }
}

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", toggleMenuItems);
```

This works perfectly, but only for the very first item, so I am now using querySelectorAll below, but to no avail.

```
const toggleButton = document.querySelectorAll(".header__nav-mobile .toggle");
const subMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".header__nav-mobile .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu");

function toggleMenuItems() {
    for (let i = 0; i < toggleButton.length; i++) {
        if (toggleButton.classList.contains("open")) {
          toggleButton .classList.remove("open");
          subMenu.classList.remove("open");
        } else {
          toggleButton.classList.add("open");
          subMenu.classList.add("open");
        }
    }
}

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", toggleMenuItems);
```

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: you need to do something like this `toogleButton[i]` or easily use a `toogleButton.forEach((btn) => { /* paste your code here */ })`

Comment: Use `toggle` instead of `contains`/`remove`/`add`. Also, what @LaaouatniAnas said..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 0):

When you run [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), you get a DOM [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) back which you can then add your event listener to, but when you run [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), you get a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) returned which you will need to iterate through to add event listeners to all the elements.  You'll need to iterate through it like an array to add that event listener to all your `toggleButton`s.

```js
const toggleButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".header__nav-mobile .toggle");

toggleButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", toggleMenuItems);
});
```

Now that said, you're going to need to modify your `toggleMenuItems` function a bit and make it more pure by passing in any elements you plan to toggle inside of it.  I would pass the each `toggleButton` into the `toggleMenuItems` listener and then have it query for the proper `subMenu` for that specific `toggleButton`.

Depending on how you have your `html` written will dictate how you go about accessing the proper `subMenu` in your `toggleMenuItems` function.